# Will iMac boot chime play if there is no CPU?

Tags: audio, imac, startup, hardware, efi

So I got this iMac from auction, as is. The iMac chimes when I press the start button but the screen remains black. Is it possible that the iMac chimes if it has no CPU? I just wanna make sure if the iMac indeed has the CPU because I noticed missing screws on the front screen. I did not disassemble the logic board as I never done it. So is it possible to not have a CPU and still have the iMac play a chime when it boots up?

Comment: There are a very long line of iMacs. Can you post a picture or actual model year / type?

Comment: its 27" 2011 model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will be no boot-up chime (an [EFI ROM tone](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202768)) if the CPU is missing. The chime only plays if the power-on self test completes successfully, which is impossible without a CPU.

Comment: well makes lots of sense. I am little less worried now. Will power-on self test also detects GPU? In other words does chime also confirms presence of GPU? As these models are notorious for bad GPU's so someone might have removed it to put in another iMac

Comment: @gfdsal I don't know. Maybe ask that as a separate question.